# Delay to download html2pdf in lararvel using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, html2pdf

I am using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf to convert html page to pdf download. But I have little problem. Download process so long to loading. Here is my code. 
In controller

```
$sale = Sale::find($id);
    view()->share('sale', $sale);
    $pdf = PDF::loadview('sale.slip_out_pdf');
    return $pdf->download('slip_out.pdf');
```

Routes

```
Route::get('pdf/{id}', 'SaleController@pdf');
```

view

```
<a href="{{ action('SaleController@pdf',[$sale->id]) }}">Download PDF</a>
```

Comment: What is your setup? Are you testing locally on a windows machine using xampp or wamp? I had a similar issue where html2pdf took > 2 Minutes to generate on Wamp and > 30 sec und xampp. Now that i have it on a real server it's like < 2 sec

Comment: thanks! I will test on real server.

Comment: which version of laravel are you using?